# how do i use string.replace() to replace only when the string is exactly matching

Tags: python, string, list, dataframe, replace

I have a dataframe with a list of poorly spelled clothing types. I want them all in the same format , an example is i have "trous" , "trouse" and "trousers", i would like to replace the first 2 with "trousers".

I have tried using string.replace but it seems its getting the first "trous" and changing it to "trousers" as it should and when it gets to "trouse", it works also but when it gets to "trousers"  it makes "trousersersers"! i think its taking the strings which contain trous and trouse and trousers and changing them.

Is there a way i can limit the string.replace to just look for exactly "trous".

here's what iv troied so far, as you can see i have a good few changes to make, most of them work ok but its the likes of trousers and t-shirts which have a few similar changes to be made thats causing the upset.

```
 newTypes=[]
for string in types:
    underwear = string.replace(('UNDERW'), 'UNDERWEAR').replace('HANKY', 'HANKIES').replace('TIECLI', 'TIECLIPS').replace('FRAGRA', 'FRAGRANCES').replace('ROBE', 'ROBES').replace('CUFFLI', 'CUFFLINKS').replace('WALLET', 'WALLETS').replace('GIFTSE', 'GIFTSETS').replace('SUNGLA', 'SUNGLASSES').replace('SCARVE', 'SCARVES').replace('TROUSE ', 'TROUSERS').replace('SHIRT', 'SHIRTS').replace('CHINO', 'CHINOS').replace('JACKET', 'JACKETS').replace('KNIT', 'KNITWEAR').replace('POLO', 'POLOS').replace('SWEAT', 'SWEATERS').replace('TEES', 'T-SHIRTS').replace('TSHIRT', 'T-SHIRTS').replace('SHORT', 'SHORTS').replace('ZIP', 'ZIP-TOPS').replace('GILET ', 'GILETS').replace('HOODIE', 'HOODIES').replace('HOODZIP', 'HOODIES').replace('JOGGER', 'JOGGERS').replace('JUMP', 'SWEATERS').replace('SWESHI', 'SWEATERS').replace('BLAZE ', 'BLAZERS').replace('BLAZER ', 'BLAZERS').replace('WC', 'WAISTCOATS').replace('TTOP', 'T-SHIRTS').replace('TROUS', 'TROUSERS').replace('COAT', 'COATS').replace('SLIPPE', 'SLIPPERS').replace('TRAINE', 'TRAINERS').replace('DECK', 'SHOES').replace('FLIP', 'SLIDERS').replace('SUIT', 'SUITS').replace('GIFTVO', 'GIFTVOUCHERS')
    
    newTypes.append(underwear)
    types = newTypes
```

Comment: Are the strings in types exactly one word long, or are they longer phrases (like `boxer underw` or `wrong trouse`)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're okay with not using `string.replace()`, you can simply do this:

```
lst = ["trousers", "trous" , "trouse"]

for i in range(len(lst)):
    if "trous" in lst[i]:
        lst[i] = "trousers"
        
print(lst)
# Prints ['trousers', 'trousers', 'trousers']
```

This checks if the shortest substring, `trous`, is part of the string, and if so converts the entire string to `trousers`.

Comment: this means i have to do this for every string, i am already using a huge line of code attaching all the string replace together.

Comment: @PeterSnee Not EVERY string, only strings where there are more than 1 synonyms. Also, I don't know any way to do this with replace unfortunately.

Comment: no prob, cheers, i unfortunately just worked around it and did another string replace for all the mistakes the first one caused, worked out ok in the end

Answer (score 0):

Use a dict for string to be replaced:

```
 d={
  'trous': 'trouser',
  'trouse': 'trouser',
  # ...
 }

 newtypes=[d.get(string,string) for string in types]
```

d.get(string,string) will return string if string is not in d.